# i have errors in the code that i don't know how to solve

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

my web is only work with fairfox and not with chrom 
but when i'm running the html with netbeams on chrom the web is working just fine

i dont know what to do and i need to submit it in the next 10 hours
you can download the entire project here:

[the project](https://f2h.nana10.co.il/x0m4z605g1lo)

[the errores image:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TIxry.png)

index html:

```
<html ng-app="MyApp">
<head>
    <title>Web Site Student</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="_scripts/jquery-3.1.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="_scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="_scripts/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="_scripts/myapp.js"></script>
    <script src="_scripts/ctrols.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="_scripts/json.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href="_css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

        <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteStudent</a>
                </div>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#/list">Data</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#/analysis">Analysis</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#/monitor">Monitor</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
    <div  ng-view>

    </div>
</body>
```

ctrols code:

```
    (function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('MyApp')
        .controller('ListCtrl', ListCtrl); // ControllerName & functionName can be the same name, but not required.

    ListCtrl.$inject = ['$scope'];
    function ListCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.personalDetails = json

        $scope.addNew = function(){
            $scope.personalDetails.push({ 
                'id':"", 
                'name':"",
                'lastName':"",
                'email':"",
                'grade':"",
                'subject':"",
            })
        } 
        $scope.addNew = function(){
            $scope.personalDetails.push({ 
                'id':"", 
                'name':"",
                'lastName':"",
                'email':"",
                'grade':"",
                'subject':"",
            })
        }    
        $scope.remove = function(){
            var newDataList=[]
            angular.forEach($scope.personalDetails, function(selected){
                if(!selected.selected){
                    newDataList.push(selected)
                }
            })
            $scope.personalDetails = newDataList
            json= $scope.personalDetails
        }
    }
})();

(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('MyApp')
        .controller('AnalysisCtrl', AnalysisCtrl); // ControllerName & functionName can be the same name, but not required.

    AnalysisCtrl.$inject = ['$scope'];
    function AnalysisCtrl($scope) {
            $scope.personalDetails = json

$(document).ready(function() {
  $.getScript('http://www.chartjs.org/assets/Chart.js',function(){

      var data = {
          labels : ["January","February","March","April","May","June","July"],
          datasets : [
              {
                  fillColor : "rgba(220,220,220,0.5)",
                  strokeColor : "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                  pointColor : "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                  pointStrokeColor : "#fff",
                  data : [65,59,90,81,56,55,40]
              },
              {
                  fillColor : "rgba(151,187,205,0.5)",
                  strokeColor : "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
                  pointColor : "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
                  pointStrokeColor : "#fff",
                  data : [28,48,40,19,96,27,100]
              }
          ]
      }

      var options = {
          animation: true
      };
      var c = $('#myChart')
      var ct = c.get(0).getContext('2d')
      var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d")
      new Chart(ctx).Bar(data,options)

  })
})
    }
})();

(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('MyApp')
        .controller('MonitorCtrl', MonitorCtrl); // ControllerName & functionName can be the same name, but not required.

    MonitorCtrl.$inject = ['$scope'];
    function MonitorCtrl($scope) {
        $scope.student = json;
    }
})();
```

myapp code:

```
 (function () {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('MyApp', [
        "ngRoute"
    ]);
}());

(function () {
    angular.module('MyApp')
        .config(
            function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
                $locationProvider.hashPrefix('');
                $routeProvider
                    .when("/list", {
                        templateUrl: "addon/list.html",
                        controller: "ListCtrl"
                    })
                    .when("/analysis", {
                        templateUrl: "addon/analysis.html",
                        controller: "AnalysisCtrl"
                    })
                    .when("/monitor", {
                        templateUrl: "addon/monitor.html",
                        controller: "MonitorCtrl"
                    })
                    .otherwise({
                        redirectTo: "/list"
                    })
            });
}());
```

Comment: That's not fair of the fox

Answer (score 0):

To put it simply, your code is a basic mess. You have extra characters in some places, and missing characters in others. You do not have a good file structure, you reference files that do not exist (_css/stayle.css), and your have improper indentation.

Next time, please upload your code to github, instead of a random website with wait times to download, and foreign language.

For a better understanding of Angular, and its file structure, please read through the Angular 1 Style guide by John Papa:
https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md

and/or by Todd Motto: https://toddmotto.com/ultimate-guide-to-learning-angular-js-in-one-day/

---

That being said, I think your main issues lie in ctrols.js and myapp.js files.

I removed 'SuperCtrl' for simplicity. You can add it when you have a better understanding of Angular. Your myapp.js file should look similar to this:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('MyApp', [
        "ngRoute"
    ]);
}());

(function () {
    angular.module('MyApp')
        .config(
            function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
                $locationProvider.hashPrefix('');
                $routeProvider
                    .when("/list", {
                        templateUrl: "addon/list.html",
                        controller: "ListCtrl"
                    })
                    .when("/analysis", {
                        templateUrl: "addon/analysis.html",
                        controller: "AnalysisCtrl"
                    })
                    .when("/monitor", {
                        templateUrl: "addon/monitor.html",
                        controller: "RemoveCtrl"
                    })
                    .otherwise({
                        redirectTo: "/list"
                    })
            });
}());
```

Each of your controller in ctrols.js file should be in similar format:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('MyApp')
        .controller('ControllerName', functionName); // ControllerName & functionName can be the same name, but not required.

    functionName.$inject = ['$scope'];
    function functionName($scope) {
        // Controller code here
    }
})();
```

That should be enough to get your going in the right direction.

After updating the code, I was able to see the UI of Data & Analysis tabs:
[image]
[image]

Comment: thank you for your quick repll i was only start to lern angularjs yasterdy and i will be better i short time i hope :)

Comment: can you uplode the changes thet you made its still not working to me and i dont know whay and i want to see what you did

Comment: What errors do you see in the console log? Try to resolve those, if you can't, update your post to include the errors and the changes you made. Make sure your libraries are imported in the proper order (i.e. import jQuery before others). On a separate note, you haven't selected a correct answer on your previous question you asked. if any answers helped you the most, go and check-mark it in your previous question.

Comment: i updated what i change and add an image with the errors

Comment: hi ali i hope you can help me in this problem because i relly need your help